# How to create popup beneath element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to know how to create a popup beneath an element clicked.

I found a w3 schools site that shows exactly what i want (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_popup.asp), but instead I want it to appear from the bottom like in this image:[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
/* Popup container - can be anything you want */
.popup {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* The actual popup */
.popup .popuptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -80px;
}

/* Popup arrow */
.popup .popuptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

/* Toggle this class - hide and show the popup */
.popup .show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}

/* Add animation (fade in the popup) */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0;} 
  to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0;}
  to {opacity:1 ;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body style="text-align:center">

<h2>Popup</h2>

<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">Click me to toggle the popup!
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">A Simple Popup!</span>
</div>

<script>
// When the user clicks on div, open the popup
function myFunction() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have tried modifing the above code to make it appear below the element, but I would always be unsuccessful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I edited the .popuptext to change position of the box and the arrow class to make it point up. Good luck.

```js
// When the user clicks on div, open the popup
function myFunction() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
/* Popup container - can be anything you want */

.popup {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  color: #555;
}


/* The actual popup */

.popup .popuptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: -225%; /* NEW POSITION */
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -80px;
}


/* Popup arrow */
/*
.popup .popuptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}
*/
/* NEW ARROW */
.popup .popuptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #555;
}


/* Toggle this class - hide and show the popup */

.popup .show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}


/* Add animation (fade in the popup) */

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<body style="text-align:center">

  <h2>Popup</h2>

  <div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">Click me to toggle the popup!
    <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">A Simple Popup!</span>
  </div>
```